# Return array without quotes

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

**The scenario**

I want to push product gtins to Google Merchant Center.

**What I'm getting**

```
"products": ['{"gtin":"5704378978422"}', '{"gtin":"5704378978057"}']
```

**What I want to get**

Without single quotes for each array member in the format:

```
"products": [{"gtin":"GTIN1"}, {"gtin":"GTIN2"}]
```

As described in step 3 here: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7519329

**My Google Tag Manager setup**

1. I have created a Data Layer Variable {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products}} from *ecommerce.purchase.products*
2. I have created a Custom Javascript variable with the following code:

**Code:**

```
function() {
  var products = {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products}};
  return products.reduce(function(arr, prod) { 
    return arr.concat("{" + '"' + "gtin" + '"' + ":" + '"' + prod.gtin + '"' + "}" ); }, []);
}
```

**What would be the best way to do this**

I'm new to JavaScript, and would appreciate any comments and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `concat` function you are creating a string concatenation, not an object.
You should probably use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `reduce`. Like this:

```
function() {
  var products = {{DLV - ecommerce.purchase.products}};
  return products.map(function(prod) { 
    return {"gtin": prod.gtin};
  });
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following for my variable in GTM Preview Mode: 
[{gtin: '5704378978422'}, {gtin: '5704378978057'}]
How can I turn this into:
[{"gtin": "5704378978422"}, {"gtin": "5704378978057"}]

In Google Chrome Inspect I get:
products:"[object Object],[object Object]"
(and a console error, but it's the Google API)

Comment: @nteglskov is that not what you are expecting? They both represent exactly the same JS data

Comment: I want it to be exactly like this (quotes included):
[{"gtin": "5704378978422"}, {"gtin": "5704378978057"}]

Comment: These quotes around "gtin" are simply how the object is displayed to you. They have nothing to do with the actual object data. If the service API accepts an object *with* quotes, it will accept one *without* quotes as well. If you need to send a JSON string instead of an object to the service (which I doubt), you can `JSON.stringify` it - which will return a serialized string of the object (including quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want this?

```js
const product = ['{"gtin":"5704378978422"}', '{"gtin":"5704378978057"}']
const newProduct = product.map(row => JSON.parse(row))
console.log(newProduct)
```

Comment: This solves the issue, but at the moment it's not compatible with Google Tag Manager, which should be used according to OP. "This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: const declaration." and "[..]: arrow function. "

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this in context with my current code.
Can you please explain me?

Comment: @nteglskov try to replace your `return products.reduce` line

Comment: @kkangil Google Manager gives me the error kgrg describes above, not allowing me to publish the container

Comment: change `const` to `var`, and change `row => JSON.parse(row)` with `function(row) { return JSON.parse(row);}`